# Why is Solve not able to solve the following system of coupled non-linear equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following two coupled non-linear equations

```
eqns = {0 == \[Alpha] (I*d - k/2 - I*g*\[Alpha] (b + Conjugate[b])) && 
   0 == I*w_m*b - I*g*Abs[\[Alpha]] - \[Gamma]/2*b}
Solve[eqns, {\[Alpha], b}]
```

Here, $\alpha$ and $b$ are my two complex variables I want to solve for. The other variables are constant, i.e. $d, k, g, \gamma$ are experimental constants.

Now, when I run this commmand, Solve gives the error message:

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

Why is that?

Comment: You need a space between variable names. E.g.: "Ig\[Alpha]". Further do  not use capitalized variable names as they are reserved for the system. E.g. "D" is an derivative operator.

Comment: I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Variable names should not include a pattern (`_`). Change `w_m` to `wm`. If you want it displayed as a subscript, use `Format[wm] := Subscript[w, m]`. Are the experimental constants assumed to be real?

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes they are real.

Answer (score 3):

Let us somewhat rewrite `eqns`, making use of `b + Conjugate[b]=2*Re[b]` and `Abs[\[Alpha]]=Sqrt[Re[\[Alpha]]^2 + Im[\[Alpha]]^2]` and `w=w_m`.Then the following works.

```
eqns = {0 == \[Alpha] (I*d - k/2 - I*g*\[Alpha] *(2*Re[b])) && 
0 == I*w*b -  I*g*Sqrt[Re[\[Alpha]]^2 + Im[\[Alpha]]^2] - \[Gamma]/2*b};
f[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_] := Solve[eqns /. {g -> a1, d -> a2, w -> a3, 
k -> a4, \[Gamma] -> a5}, {\[Alpha], b}]
f[1, Pi*I, 1, 2, -3]
```

> `{{\[Alpha] -> 0,  b -> 0}, {\[Alpha] -> (I (169 + 338 \[Pi] + 169 \[Pi]^2)^(1/4))/( 2 Sqrt[2]),  b -> ((2/13 + (3 I)/13) (169 + 338 \[Pi] + 169 \[Pi]^2)^(1/4))/Sqrt[ 2]}}`

```
f[1.1,Pi*I,-I/2,2,-3]
```

> `{{\[Alpha] -> 0, b -> 0}}`

It should be noticed `Reduce` is preferable, since `Solve` may use non-equivalent transforms.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I understand, this gets you the solution for specific parameter values, which are provided as input to the function `f`. Is there a general solution as well?